# Is there a function to make user choose which operation to perform?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote code for two functions for a dictionary to be sorted either by key or by value in ascending order. I would like the user to be able to choose which sort function they want to be run by value or by key. My code for both is below.

```
d = {'b': 1, 'y': 12, 'c': 7, 'm': 2}
sort_d = sorted(d.items())
for i in sort_d:
    print(i[0], i[1])


d = {'b': 1, 'y': 12, 'c': 7, 'm': 2}
sort_d = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
for i in sort_d:
    print(i[0], i[1])
```

Comment: `s = input()` then check `s`

Comment: Just use the `reverse` keyword argument to `sorted`: `descending = input("sort descending? ").startswith("y"); print(sorted([3,1,2], reverse=descending))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `input` and `if-elif-else` to do it.

code:

```
def sort_by_key(d):
    sort_d = sorted(d.items())
    for i in sort_d:
        print(i[0], i[1])

def sort_by_value(d):
    sort_d = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
    for i in sort_d:
        print(i[0], i[1])

d = {'b': 1, 'y': 12, 'c': 7, 'm': 2}
choose = input("Which sort function they want to be run? input 'key' or 'value'")
if choose == "key":
    sort_by_key(d)
elif choose == "value":
    sort_by_value(d)
else:
    print("invaild input")
```

result:

```
Which sort function they want to be run? input 'key' or 'value'key
b 1
c 7
m 2
y 12

Which sort function they want to be run? input 'key' or 'value'value
b 1
m 2
c 7
y 12

Which sort function they want to be run? input 'key' or 'value'xxxx
invaild input
```

**EDIT**:with a little improve to remove duplicate code

code:

```
def sort(d,keyfunc = None):
    sort_d = sorted(d.items(), key=keyfunc)
    for i in sort_d:
        print(i[0], i[1])

d = {'b': 1, 'y': 12, 'c': 7, 'm': 2}
operation_dic = {"key":None,"value":lambda x: x[1]}
while True:
    choose = input("Which sort function they want to be run? input 'key' or 'value'")
    if choose in operation_dic:
        sort(d,operation_dic[choose])
        break
    else:
        print("invaild input")
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no function that does exactly that per se, so you have write some code to do it yourself.

Applying the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle to avoid repetitious code, you could use [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to define a suitable `key` function for the `sorted()` function to use.

Here's what I mean:

```
from operator import itemgetter


while True:
    choice = input('sort by key or value (k or v)? ').lower()
    if choice in {'k', 'v'}:
        break
    else:
        print("Sorry, that's not a valid input, try again.\n")

keyfunc = itemgetter(0 if choice == 'k' else 1)

d = {'b': 1, 'y': 12, 'c': 7, 'm': 2}

print()
sort_d = sorted(d.items(), key=keyfunc)
for i in sort_d:
    print(i[0], i[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define these functions and ask for user's input and then based on that input run the function:

```
answer = input("Type 1 to sort by values or 2 to sort by keys: ")
if answer == "1":
    sort_by_values(your_dict)
else:
    sort_by_key(your_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is were the use of control statements: `if...elif...else:`.

This is what you can try.

```
d = {'b': 1, 'y': 12, 'c': 7, 'm': 2}
x=input("How to sort the dicyionary? 'Key' or 'Value': ")
if x.lower() =="key":
    sort_d = sorted(d.items())
    for i in sort_d:
        print(i[0], i[1])
elif x.lower()=="value":  
    sort_d = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
    for i in sort_d:
        print(i[0], i[1])
else: print("Invalid input. Please try again.")
```